# How to change clicked div style without state in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to change the style of a div when I click on it, but if I use state and make a condition for mapped element, each element will have the have the same style.

How can I change the style just of a clicked div?

This is the code:

```
   {messages.map((e, index) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <div>
              {e.asnwerType == 'unclear' && (
                <>
                  <div onClick={() => setShow(!showAdditional)}>
                    {e.additionalText}:
                  </div>
                  <div
                    className={`${showAdditional ? 'block' : 'hidden'}`}
                  >
                    {e.message.map((el, index) => {
                      return (
                        <div>
                          {index + 1 + ': ' + el}
                        </div>
                      );
                    })}
                  </div>
                </>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
```

Comment: Make sure you're using a unique key for each element in the map, then push the key to a highlightedKey state, which conditionally highlights it